# Regex replace numbers but the ones starting with 0 that aren't float

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following string:

> ' "z":"100", "a":"+0.5", "b":"-0.578", "c":"-.5", "d":".55", "e":"-5",
>   "f":"01234", "g":"0.999", "i":"153.35" '

I'm trying to convert every number in this string while retaining the negative sign, **except the ones starting with a 0 that arent float**. In other words, I'm trying to convert to

> ' "z":100, "a":0.5, "b":-0.578, "c":-.5, "d":.55, "e":-5, "f":"01234", "g":0.999, "i":153.35 '

This is what I have so far

```
preg_replace('/((?:\:")(?:[\+])?[\-]?([0-9\.]+?)[0-9]+(?:"))/', '$1', $string);
```

Which isn't enough.. The hard part is to keep the **"** around **01234** while removing them for the other numbers..

Basically I'd like to ignore

```
(\:"[0][0-9]+")
```

[Regexr link](http://regexr.com/3ekpd)

Comment: Do you want `01234` or `1234`, the F value?

Comment: I want to keep "01234" because it is in fact a postal code that could contain a letter so every number that starts by 0 that isn't float should be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `(:)"(?!0\d+")\+?(-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+)"` and replace it with `$1$2`.

See [ideone](http://ideone.com/0nA3hA)

```
$str = '"z":"100", "a":"+0.5", "b":"-0.578", "c":"-.5", "d":".55", "e":"-5", "f":"01234", "g":"0.999", "i":"153.35", "0":"5"';
$pattern = '/(:)"(?!0\d+")\+?(-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+)"/';
print(preg_replace($pattern, '$1$2', $str));
```

Comment: So I've found out that this regex will unfortunately convert "0":"55" to 0:55. Anyway you could fix it so it doesn't try to convert numbers before the : ?

Comment: Thanks again, but now convert "0":"124" to "0":

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/xbafiQ/1) to match all the numbers between quotes:

```
(?<=")(?!0\d)[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?=")
```

EDIT: Sorry misread your question, I updated the regex to match every number but the ones beginning with 0 that aren't floats

Comment: I'm fine with multiple preg_replace if it helps

Comment: Note that `01.2` won't be matched at all with this, even if it's a float.